# Putting numbers of Quoted text overflows

Tags: bug, markdown, markdown-rendering

I was writing a question in SO and I used a block-quote, here is the result

[image]

Here you can see the Numbers in block-quote overflow, while the letters in the other block-quote are not.

Am also adding a link to the question [Concatenating two R.string leads to numbers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59444468/concatenating-two-r-string-leads-to-numbers)

I am using both Firefox (71.0) and Chrome (79.0.3945.88).

Is it a UI Bug?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

This is by design.

In markdown, a number followed by a period and a space creates an ordered list in html.

Aka:

```
<ol start="32908529">
  <li>23492492</li>
</ol>
```

To prevent that from happening escape the period with a backslash:

```
> 32908529\. 23492492
```

resulting in

> 32908529. 23492492

Answer (score 1):

Seems like a bug. But you can avoid it by not adding dot (`.`) after first number:

> 32908529. 23492492
>
> 32908529 23492492

Or markup it as code

```
32908529. 23492492
```